# Concurrency parallel_for using too much memory

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing

I have a vector of gray scale images (loaded using OpenCV 3). Each image is 2560x64800 pixels and the vector can hold up to 23 images. Thus the max size of the vector is approximately 3.6 GB. I need to do a "blob detection" on each image and to speed up things, I would like to run the image analysis using parallel processing of the images. For all detected blobs a small 40x40 pixels image should be returned. The entire data set consists of up to 13 sets of images - I have chosen to make the outer loop a normal sequential for-loop:

```
for (size_t cn = 0; cn < numberOfChannels.size(); ++cn)
{
    vector<Mat> imageVector = readImages(...);

    // Loop through images in "imageVector"
    concurrency::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(imageVector.size()), [&](size_t ii)
    {
        // Detect blobs
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints = detectBlobs(imageVector[ii], false);

        // Return result
        theSnips[cn][ii] = collectImageSnips(imageVector[ii], keypoints, 40);
    });
};
```

The function declaration for the two functions "detectBlobs" (based on OpenCV 3 "SimpleBlobDetection") and "collectImageSnips" are:

```
vector<KeyPoint> detectBlobs(Mat image, bool useTestImage)

vector<Mat> collectImageSnips(Mat image, vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints, int rectSize)
```

When I run the supplied "parallel_for" loop I would expect (hope) that 3.6 GB RAM would be used to store the loaded "imageVector" and for each thread an additional approx. 160 GB (+ a minor overhead for the blob detection as well as storing the small images of the detected blobs) would be the result. Instead memory usage explodes as each thread takes up an additional 3.6 GB (+ additional overhead), and Windows stops responding.

As I am a novice C++-coder I might have missed something obvious, but is what i see the expected behavior? And more importantly, is there a way to avoid multiplying the entire imageVector for each thread?

NB! Since the images that I want to analyse are a reconstruction from a large number of smaller images, simply reading one image at a time without a large disk I/O overhead is not possible.

NB! Though reducing the allowed number of threads will solve the problem of Windows crashing, it is not an acceptable solution since CPU-resources will not be properly utilized.

Comment: What is 160 GB memory?? I think you meant 160 MB. Am I right???

Comment: How much memory does it use if you break in debugger after `readImages()`?

Comment: Sure I meant 160 MB per image - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If I break before and after reading the images, the memory used by loading the images is approximately 3.6 GB - i.e. what I expected.